# Jacobi Symbol: $\sum_{n=1}^{n=p}\left(\frac{n^2+a}{p}\right)=-1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, jacobi-symbol

Show that if $(a,p)=1$, $p$ an odd prime then, $\sum_{n=1}^{n=p}\left(\frac{n^2+a}{p}\right)=-1$,
where $\left(\frac{n^2+a}{p}\right)$ is the Jacobi symbol.

This question has been taken from the book : An introduction to theory of numbers by Niven, Zuckerman, Montgomery. Section 3.3., question 20.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you write more than just" I couldn't understand that"? What exactly is the problem? Did you try to understand the other duplicates?

Comment: I did't find any other duplicates. How to proceed using that hint is not at all clear to me.

Comment: You did not search long, right? Start with [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588858/how-to-calculate-such-sums-of-legendre-symbols).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Let me go through it. +1