# Show $x^2+y^2 \equiv1\pmod p$ has $p-1$ solutions if $p \equiv1\pmod4$ and...

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

Question:

Show the equation $x^2+y^2 \equiv1\pmod p$ has $p-1$ solutions if $p \equiv1\pmod4$, and $p+1$ solutions if $p \equiv 3\pmod4$

I'm really stuck on this one. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: $p$ is a prime ?

Comment: If $p=9$, the quadratic residues are $1,4,0,7,7,0,4,1,0$ and there are only $6$ solutions...

Comment: @user21820 Are you just computing $x^2$ for $1,\ldots, 9$, and not $x^2 + y^2$ for all pairs?

Comment: @JoeTait: Pairs of course. Did you get more than 6 solutions? If you count permutations, then 12.

Comment: I see what you meant - I thought you were claiming you had listed all possible outcomes of $x^2 + y^2$, but you are pointing out that there are six pairs from the above that add to one. Sorry, just a misreading.

Comment: @JoeTait: Ah okay. And I still don't understand why Xorserq hasn't included the condition in the question..

Comment: This question is from a test, and it wasn't mention there that $p$ is a prime. I guess it's their mistake. Sorry about that

Comment: Well that sounds sub-optimal then. I hope it wasn't too important.

Comment: @Xorserq: Ah I see. I'm done with the 4k+1 primes and working on the 4k+3 case now.

Comment: Sigh I give up...

Comment: See my solution for general case http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398200/the-number-of-solutions-of-ax2by2-equiv-1-pmodp-is-p-frac-abp/398245#398245

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is a prime of the form $4k+1$,

Let $r$ be a primitive root mod $p$ (which can be proven by various means)

Let $i = r^k$

$i^2 = r^{2k} = -1$ (mod $p$) because $(i^2)^2 = r^{p-1} = 1$ (mod $p$)

If $1 = x^2-(iy)^2 = (x+iy)(x-iy)$,

Let $a = x+iy$

$x = (a+a^{-1})2^{-1}$

$y = (a-a^{-1})(2i)^{-1}$

Therefore there is a bijection between $\{ (x,y) : x^2+y^2 = 1 \space(\text{mod } p)\}$ and $\{ a : a \in [1..p-1] \}$

If $p$ is a prime of the form $4k+3$,

I can't prove it.

Comment: Can anyone give a completely elementary proof for the second part? I'm still interested in seeing one.