# A question about Quadratic residue

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

I need help with this question :
Prove that for each prime number p there exist $a,b \in Z$ such that $-1\equiv a^{2}+b^{2}\pmod p $

When $p\equiv1\pmod4$ it is easy because -1 is a quadratic residue, I got stuck when $p\equiv3\pmod4$

Comment: This is a special case of [an earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/891861/11619). Probably the argument has presented even earlier, but I couldn't find it easily.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: suppose for the sake of contradiction that $-1-a^2$ is not a quadratic residue mod $p$, for any $a \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, p-1\}$. Then count how many quadratic nonresidues you get as a result. Use the fact that $x^2 \equiv y^2 \mod p$ if and only if $x \equiv \pm y \mod p$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$, in the sequence $\{2p-1, 6p-1, 10p-1,\ldots,4np+2p-1,\ldots\}$ there are infinitely many primes (Dirichlet's theorem) and all of them are $\equiv 1\pmod 4$.

Let $q$ be any prime from this sequence. Since $q\equiv 1\pmod 4$, there exists $a$ and $b$ such that $q=a^2+b^2$. Therefore
$$a^2+b^2\equiv q\equiv 4np+2p-1\equiv -1\pmod p$$

Comment: I don't see how this helps. Let $q = 4np+2p-1$ be prime, then there exists an $a$ so that $-1 \equiv a^2 \mod q$, which means $a^2+1 = x(4np+2p-1)$ for some $x \in \mathbb Z$. Then $a^2+1 \equiv -x \mod p$, so... ??? Was this what you were suggesting, or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Edited. I hope it helps now.