# Prove that there exist integers $x, y$ so that $2x^2+3y^2-r$ is divisible by a given prime larger than 3.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Prove that there exist integers $x, y$ so that $2x^2+3y^2-r$ is divisible by some fixed prime larger than 3.

$r$ is also an integer.

Comment: To clarify : For any given $r$, such $x$ and $y$ have to be found , right ?

Comment: Hint:  there are $\frac {p+1}2$ residues of the form $2n^2 \pmod p$ and the same number of the form $-3m^2+r\pmod p$.  (at least for $p>3$)

Comment: See. e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891861/sum-of-two-squares-modulo-p) for a similar problem.

Comment: We are given $p, r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p > 3$ be the fixed prime.

We consider the following $p + 1$ numbers:

- $2x^2$ for $x = 0, 1, \dots, \frac {p - 1}2$;
- $r - 3y^2$ for $y = 0, 1, \dots, \frac {p - 1}2$.

Since there are only $p$ different residues mod $p$, there must be two numbers with the same residue.

It is clear that

- $2x_1^2 \neq 2x_2^2$ for any $0 \leq x_1 < x_2 \leq \frac{p - 1}2$;
- $r - 3y_1^2 \neq r - 3y_2^2$ for any $0 \leq y_1 < y_2 \leq \frac{p - 1}2$.

Therefore there must exist $x, y$ such that $2x^2 = r - 3y^2$.